# Store table data in Model and write into document/template (Enterprise Architect)

Tags: vbscript, documentation, document, enterprise-architect

I have a problem with creating documentations on EA. I want to get my information on packages, subpackages or properties via VBScript in a table. In the next step this table should be put into my documentation or template.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the linked documents (ctrl+alt+D) that are available on each element and package to store full RTF documentation including tables and images.

Then include that linked document in your template.

You can manipulate the linked document using `EA.Element.GetLinkedDocument()` and `EA.Element.LoadLinkedDocument(string Filename)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
How can I access the linked documents (create a table and write) with VBScript?

Comment: Jacky, you should not thank me but instead flag the answer as accepted if that is what you were after.

Comment: Of course, I accept your answer :)
But I'm still searching a way to realize it.

Comment: I've added the relevant API functions